# How do Evernote get over the iOS app limitation of only being able to handle 64 push notifications at a time?

Tags: ios, ios7, uilocalnotification, evernote

How do Evernote get around the iOS limitation of having only 64 push notifications, as users are still able set up an infinite amount of reminders in the Evernote app, whilst still all being local notifications and thus not pushed from their own server.

Comment: I presume that they just register the next few notifications each time the app is launched and use something the background fetch background mode to refresh the scheduled notifications periodically

Comment: That's why I suggested background fetch mode to periodically refresh the scheduled notifications

Comment: What if they do not open the app for a long time ? Could this mean some notifications would not occur ?